# PHP query mysql database, echo long name for short table value

Tags: php, mysql, echo, long-integer

I have a table with a column which has values that are an abbreviation of longer words and the way that the table is currently being populated I can't change the values in the column.

I then have a PHP page that does a basic MySQL query and echo's those values onto the page, what I want to do is echo the values in their longer word format but have nothing to cross query - they have to be made up with variables on the page (unless someone can suggest another way):

This is what I mean:

### TABLE A - ROW 1

- A1   {long: Alpha1}
- B1   {long: Bravo1}
- C1   {long: Charlie1}
- D1   {long: Delta1}
- E1   {long: Echo1}

Is there an easier / shorter way to code the page querying the database other than doing numerous if / elseif statements:

```
if ($value == 'A1')
{
     echo 'Alpha1';
}
elseif ($value =='B1')
{
     echo 'Bravo1';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a switch statement:

```
switch ($value) {
    case 'A1' :
        echo 'Alpha1';
        break;
    case 'B1' :
        echo 'Bravo1';
        break;
    default:
        echo 'default'
        break;
}
```

Or you can use a map:

```
$map = array('A1' => 'Alpha1', 'B1' => 'Bravo1');
echo array_key_exists($value, $map) ? $map[$value] : 'default';
```

Comment: Thanks @taxicala - just read up about the switch command, that looks like a useful option.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ternary operators, like so:

```
echo ($value == 'A1') ? 'A1' : 'Bravo1';
```

Or if you have multiple conditions as you mentioned, like so:

```
echo ($value == 'A1') ?  'A1' : (($value == 'B1')  ?  'Bravo' : 'Charlie1');
```

and so on, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Build an array to store them all, using the short code as the key, and long word as the value:

```
$words = array();  
$words['A1'] = 'Alpha1';
$words['B1'] = 'Bravo1';
$words['C1'] = 'Charlie1';
$words['D1'] = 'Delta1';
$words['E1'] = 'Echo1';
```

Then call the array, using the key, to output the long word.

```
echo $words[$value];
```